# Load random CSS every 5 seconds without page refresh

Tags: javascript, html, css, random

Do you know how to load a random css **without refreshing the page**?
I would like to load a random style like the one achieved in this thread:

```
<script>
var link = [];
link[0] = "css/0.css";
link[1] = "css/1.css";
link[2] = "css/2.css";
link[3] = "css/3.css";

$(function() {
    var style = link[Math.floor(Math.random() * link.length )];
    if (document.createStyleSheet){
        document.createStyleSheet(style);
    }else{
        $('<link />',{
            rel :'stylesheet',
            type:'text/css',
            href: style
        }).appendTo('head');
    }
});
</script>
```

This code works, but is it possible to load another style randomly every 5 seconds without refreshing?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: With the above code, are you stuck with how to make it load ever 5 seconds or about how to potentially add an element to the link array?

Comment: You will need to add [interval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)

Comment: Why not load them all and simply change a class name on the body or root element?  This random stylesheet loader seems kind of hacky.

Comment: I'm stuck with how to make it load ever 5 seconds. I want to make a "mutant" web that changes a bit every 5 or 10 seconds the styles of background, font-styles, colors... I have a demo here, if you refresh you see 4 different styles: http://gregorsamsa.org/mutant/

Comment: You would also need to remove the previous `styleSheet` as well, yes?

Comment: yes, just load a new stylesheet randomly, removing the previous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe somewhere in the vicinity of this...

```js
    var links = ["css/0.css", "css/1.css", "css/2.css", "css/3.css"];
    
    function setCSS(){

       var link = document.createElement('link');

       link.rel  = 'stylesheet';
       link.href = links[ Math.floor(Math.random()*links.length) ];

       document.head.link && document.head.link.remove();

       document.head.link = link;
       document.head.appendChild(link);

    }
    
    setInterval(setCSS,5000);
    
    setCSS();
```

Comment: What is result if `<link>` element takes five seconds to load?

Comment: if `<link>` element takes 5 seconds to load you should migrate to a different service provider...

Comment: How do you know the `Content-Length` of `.css` file or network conditions? `setInteval` could be called again before styles are rendered in `document`.

Comment: if you are looking for such a solution you should look into promises, this  should work for most cases when you do not plan to load 1Mb css files in an unending loop...

Comment: Sorry but this code doesn't work either and doesn't load any css

Comment: the fiddle shows that the css is trying to load. what error do you get? is the element being added to the dom? there was a problem with the array, maybe that caused the problem

Answer (score 1):

Use **[`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval)** to do it every 5 seconds and use 'document.createElement` to create the new link.

You must also remember to remove the previously created link before adding the new one.

```js
function getLink(){
    // Find previous <link> (if exists) and remove it
    var prevLink = document.querySelector("head > link");
    if(prevLink) { 
      document.querySelector("head").removeChild(prevLink); 
    }
    
    // Get a random CSS link
    var style = links[Math.floor(Math.random() * links.length )];
  
    // Create a new <link> element and configure it
    var link = document.createElement("link");
    link.setAttribute("href", style);
    link.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
    console.log(link);

    // Inject element into the DOM
    document.querySelector("head").appendChild(link);
  
    // Once the stylesheet has finished downloading, add it to the DOM
    link.addEventListener("load", function(){   
      // Now that the new stylesheet has been applied, wait 5 seconds and 
      // then replace it again:
      setTimeout(getLink, 5000);
    });
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div i="styleMe">I'm being randomly styled.</div>
```

Comment: `javascript` at Answer does not wait for `load` event of `<link>` element. `setInterval` could be called again before styles are applied in `document`.

Comment: The new link element will be applied immediately if it is created using `.createElement`. This code works, I just tested it.

Comment: `<link>` element makes a network request. The styles may not be automatically rendered in `document` when `.createElement()` is called, depending on network conditions and `Content-Length` of `.css` file.

Comment: You still have not adjusted how `getLink` is called. At `load` event of `link`, wait five seconds before calling function again. You can append new element to `document` when element is created, though that is not same as awaiting `load` event to be dispatched.

Comment: @bertranescolà Sorry, needed to make slight adjustment to code. It will work with this code now.

Answer (score 0):

There could be a delay while new `<link>` loads; if that is issue you can use `Promise` to wait until new `<link>` is loaded before calling `loadCSS()` again

```
var link = ["0.css", "1.css", "2.css", "3.css"];

$(function() {
  function loadCSS() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
      $("link:not(:last)").remove();
      var style = link[Math.floor(Math.random() * link.length)];
      var css = $('<link />', {
          rel: 'stylesheet',
          type: 'text/css',
          href: style
        })
        .on("load", function() {
          setTimeout(function() {
            resolve(css)
          }, 5000)
        })
        .appendTo('head');
    })
    .then(function() {
      return loadCSS()
    })
  }
  loadCSS()
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/yUEJXh1szCAGB9s7VqvM?p=preview

Comment: `type=text/css` hasn't been needed for several years.

Comment: @ScottMarcus What do you mean by "hasn't been needed"? The `MIME` type of `<link>` element does not have to be `"text/css"`. An `.html` `document`, `"text/html"`, or other type of resource could be loaded at `link` element.

Comment: HTML5 specifies that the default value for `type` in a `link` element is `text/css`. Just as it specifies that the default value for `type` in a `script` element is `text/javascript`.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Virtually any type of resource can be loaded at `<link>` element.

Comment: Yes, but the default is `text/css`.

Comment: https://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-preview/the-link-element.html#dom-link-type

Comment: @ScottMarcus Would rather specify `type` explicitly, to avoid confusion.

Comment: From: https://www.w3.org/TR/html/document-metadata.html#the-link-element...*"User agents must not consider the type attribute authoritative — upon fetching the resource, user agents must not use the type attribute to determine its actual type. Only the actual type (as defined in the next paragraph) is used to determine whether to apply the resource, not the aforementioned assumed type."*

Comment: So, in actuality, you could write `type=chocholate/vanilla` and it would still work.

Comment: This code doesn't show me any css styles. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @ScottMarcus _"So, in actuality, you could write type=chocholate/vanilla and it would still work."_ That is an exaggerated interpretation of the specification _"...then a compliant user agent that supported only CSS style sheets would fetch the B and C files, and skip the A file (since text/plain is not the MIME type for CSS style sheets).

For files B and C, it would then check the actual types returned by the server. For those that are sent as text/css, it would apply the styles, but for those labeled as text/plain, or any other type, it would not."_